# Send a authorized GET HTTP Request With Key and Secret

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest

Currently im trying to send a HTTP request to this URL,

```
https://api.earn.gg/account/get?key=6c7ca4b2-96f2-4e23-8156-9aff64d84e67&secret=1a98b15357b2c5530e5e60b33bd2952c
```

but I am receiving an error that says it is not authorized and I need to send a header

```
Failed to load https://api.earn.gg/account/get?key=6c7ca4b2-96f2-4e23-8156-9aff64d84e67&secret=1a98b15357b2c5530e5e60b33bd2952c: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

is there anyway I can access this API with granted access, when I put it in my browser normaly it returns my account info, is there any way I can fix this in javascript?
My code:

```
<button onclick="dothing()">Grab</button>
<script>
function dothing() {
request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    url = "https://api.earn.gg/account/get?key=6c7ca4b2-96f2-4e23-8156-9aff64d84e67&secret=1a98b15357b2c5530e5e60b33bd2952c"
    request.open("GET", url, false); // false for synchronous request
request.send(null);
print(request.responseText)
}

</script>
```

Comment: You are making a `Cross-Origin Request`, [read about it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). Also check if the service you are accessing has documented `API`.

Comment: Is there a workaround for this? I rewrote this in python with a header and it works, but I need it in javascript

Comment: Making a request from server and making a cross-origiin-request (from client using ajax) both are different things. The API server must allow you to make cross-origiin-request by allowing your domain. Read about the `CORS` in the previous comment.